# Using PCSCD with ACR122U error

Tags: linux, nfc, mifare, pcsc, lib-nfc

I try to use the ACR122U with PCSCD with mfcuk bu on my PCSCD terminal I have a recurrent error :

```
00400285 ccid_usb.c:747:WriteUSB() write failed (3/4): -1 LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
00000063 ifdwrapper.c:371:IFDStatusICC() Card not transacted: 612
00000034 eventhandler.c:335:EHStatusHandlerThread() Error communicating to: ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 00 00
00000063 ccid_usb.c:1213:InterruptRead() libusb_submit_transfer failed: -1
```

I don't from where it comes and how to fix it...

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @PaulR It is a programming question because I use it to connect in a Python script ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you installed the drivers properly ? 
If so try [this](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/) tool. These tools are used to test a PC/SC driver, card or reader or send commands.

If so look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31865296/1849366) to check the configurations again.

Try [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34029). Instead of using libusb it suggests to use a smartcard API, like PC/SC, which takes care of the intricacies of USB for you, such as PCSC lite through C/C++, pyscard in Python, or other APIs/bindings in other languages.

I have worked with this and it works.

pyscard documentation and samples are [here](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html#the-answer-to-reset-atr). Cheers!